# Trying to access the object value from Azure key vault in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I have an object value in the key vault key of azure and trying to read the value at the startup class but the value is always null.

Program.cs

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                                var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                                    new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                                        azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                                config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                                    vaultConfig.AzureVaultUrl,
                                    keyVaultClient,
                                    new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public virtual void ConfigureSettings(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<OktaConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("OktaConfig")); // Read the value from Azure Key Vault or %APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<user_secrets_id>\secrets.json for Dev Environment
    }
```

Controller.cs

```
 public class SystemController
    {

        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly OktaConfig _oktaConfig;

        public SystemController(IConfiguration config, IOptions<OktaConfig> oktaConfig)
        {
            _config = config;
            _oktaConfig = oktaConfig.Value; // This value is null
        }        


        [HttpGet("Vaults")]
        public IActionResult GetVaultValues()
        {
            var OktaConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OktaConfig>(_config["OktaConfig"]);
            return Ok(OktaConfig);
        }
```

The **_oktaConfig** value is always null.

Here is my azure key vault value

[image]

Json structure of key secret value

```
{
        "OktaDomain": "https://dev-166545.okta.com/oauth2/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/v1/authorize",
        "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "ClientSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "redirectUrl": "https://localhost:44307"
    }
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class OktaConfig
    {
        public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }
        public string OktaDomain { get; set; }
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
    }
```

With this _config["OktaConfig"] code I am able to get the value, but I want to do dependency injection for that.

Comment: How you save object value in the Key Vault? Is it json?

Comment: yes it is JSON the structure is {
        "OktaDomain": "https://dev-166545.okta.com/oauth2/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/v1/authorize",
        "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "ClientSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "redirectUrl": "https://localhost:44307"
    } and as per my knowledge it is string of JSON on vault.

Comment: Just a quick check, you are referencing `Configuration.GetSection("OktaConfig")` but can I confirm that in your JSON within the vault the detail you posted is within the `OktaConfig` labelled section? You don't show that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick test on my side, this is my `OktaConfig` for quick test :

```
public class OktaConfig
{
    public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }   
}
```

Secret in key vault:

[image]

Other code are just same as you. But in `Startup.cs` , I use the code below to inject OktaConfig and add to `services`:

```
services.AddSingleton<OktaConfig>(sp =>
{
    var resultJson = Configuration.GetSection("<your secret name in kv>").Value;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OktaConfig>(resultJson);
});
```

Code in controller:

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
private OktaConfig oktaConfig;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger , OktaConfig oktaConfig)
{
    this.oktaConfig = oktaConfig;
    _logger = logger;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Ok(oktaConfig.RedirectUrl);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: May I know is it helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to map a key/value from KeyVault to a nested configuration, which is not possible. By default all secrets are written to root Configuration. However, `IConfiguration` implementation in netcore has a feature how to achieve this.
For Example when you set the key "Section1:Key1" the section "Section1" key 'Key1'  is set.

```
Configuration["Section1:Key1"]="value"
var section1 = Configuration.GetSection("Section1");
```

Now you only need to write the configuration from KeyVault to Configuration object in this format. `DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager` class can do this conversion for you, just save the key in KeyVault in appropriate format. Just write the separator '--' instead of ':'
In my example you would use 'Section1--Key1'.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.0) is very good source of information about this topic.

Comment: Does this gonna work services.Configure<OktaConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("OktaConfig")); when I use the Azure key vault key structure ?

Comment: Doesn't it create lots of keys and values? Do you think this is the right approach?

Comment: Yes, it does create a lot of entries, but you are limited with the functionality of KeyVault. If you are ok with it, you can store under a specific key a complete json. We have this way stored firebase json file in KeyVault. However, in this case, you need to modify the implementation how is the configuration object deserialized.