# Read AzureKeyVault secret value for email setting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, azure-keyvault

I have model for email setting

```
public class EmailSettingsModel {
    public string MailServer { get; set; }
    public int MailPort { get; set; }
    public string SenderName { get; set; }
    public string Sender { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I put secret value in Azure Key vault

> MailServer:smtp.gmail.com; MailPort:587; SenderName:SenderName;
>   Sender:the.sender@gmail.com; Password:123!2019#

In the `Startup.cs` file, I put my code, register it with the run time:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //this appSetting can return value from Azure Key Vault, the secret key.
    var appSetting = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureKeyVaultEmail");

    services.Configure<EmailSettingsModel>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureKeyVaultEmail"));
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

    services.AddOptions();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

For injection in class

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    private readonly EmailSettingsModel _emailSettings;

    public EmailSender (IOptions<EmailSettingsModel> emailSettings) {

        _emailSettings = emailSettings.Value;
    }
}
```

But `_emailSettings` always `null`. For '_emailSettings', it suppose return value

```
MailServer = smtp.gmail.com
MailPort = 587
SenderName = SenderName
Sender = the.sender@gmail.com
Password = 123!2019#
```

Why `_emailSettings` always return `null` ? Do I miss something ?
I try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-json-file-in-asp-net-core) as reference

Comment: @JoeyCai, It works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Startup.cs , I use the code below to inject `EmailSettingsModel` and add to services:

```
services.AddSingleton<EmailSettingsModel>(sp =>
{
    var resultJson = Configuration.GetSection("<your secret name in kv>").Value;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailSettingsModel>(resultJson);
});
```

And in HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly EmailSettingsModel emailSender;
    public HomeController(EmailSettingsModel _emailSender)
    {
        emailSender = _emailSender;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var a = emailSender.MailServer ;
        return View();
    }
}
```

And you will get the keyvault value. You could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316522/trying-to-access-the-object-value-from-azure-key-vault-in-asp-net-core).

Answer (score 1):

From the code which is mentioned in the question, it was not explained if you have written the valid configuration for Azure key vault which would be something standard like below, hope you have added that.

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                                var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                                    new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                                        azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                                config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                                    vaultConfig.AzureVaultUrl,
                                    keyVaultClient,
                                    new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
```

Also for reading complex object from key vault i would suggest you to write something like below:

```
services.AddSingleton<EmailSettingsModel >(sp =>
{
    var resultJson = Configuration.GetSection("AzureKeyVaultEmail").Value;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailSettingsModel>(resultJson);
});
```

Also as i can see in the question , below string doesn't look like a valida json format:

```
MailServer:smtp.gmail.com; MailPort:587; SenderName:SenderName; Sender:the.sender@gmail.com;
```

Please change it in a valid format and it should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for giving effort with my code. I ignore including azure key vault configuration because it's already returned value. Actually, in AKV, it has 2 keys for dB connection string & email setting. Let's focus on 'Configuration.GetSection to JSON. Let me try & I'll be back to you soon.

Comment: Sure, let me know how it goes.

Comment: I've tried some JSON formats and got error. I tried validate Json format through http://json2csharp.com. Eventually, I got Json format that return no error for EmailSetting to match with EmailSettingModel but the return of 'JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailSettingsModel>' still null. This is Json formaat that I put in AKV secrets and return null: {
EmailSettingsModel: {
 MailServer: "smtp.gmail.com",
 MailPort: 587,
 SenderName: "SenderName",
 Sender: "The.sender@gmail.com",
 Password: "@!#$FASaswer"
   }
}

Comment: according to this link (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm), I made modification the JSON ({                                 
MailServer: "smtp.gmail.com",
MailPort: 587,
SenderName: "SenderName",
Sender: "The.sender@gmail.com",
Password: "@!#$FASaswer"                                          
}) and tried to get the value of JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailSettingsModel>(resultJson) as a variable. It works well but injection in EmailSender class still return null.